# configure collectd, statsd with graphite and grafana

Tags: graphite, grafana, statsd, collectd

I am trying to setup grafana with graphite on the same server.
Also I would be monitoring many remote servers from graphite.
I learnt that I could use collectd for sending out the metrics and statsd for caching.
So what should be my approach?
I have graphite and grafana installed on my server and How do I monitor the remote servers via collectd and statsd?
Do i need to install collectd and statsd on each remote servers(which are to be monitored)?

All my machines are debian

please suggest!

Comment: any advice anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Check https://my-netdata.io

You install it on all your systems, it uses 1% CPU and 20MB RAM. It pushes metrics to graphite which can be visualized by grafana (it is a visualizer itself too). Bonus: it is also a statsd server.

netdata is GPLv3+ (free and open-source)

[image: netdata infographic]